# MySQL doesn't showing id_order and max()

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT MAX( "Total spending" ), id_order 
FROM (
  SELECT "id_ordine", SUM( "quantity" * "price" ) "Total spending" 
  FROM "t_orders", "t_products" 
  WHERE "t_orders"."id_products" = "t_products"."id_products" 
  GROUP BY "id_order"
)
```

This is my query: i have to show the higher shop bill of my orders and the id_order. 
I have in t_orders 3 columns: id_order (we have some identical numbers because you can order more than 1 product ), id_product and quantity.
In t_products i have id_product, price and name.
My problem is that i have to show the id_order with higher shop bill and i tried to do this, but it doesn't work D:

Sorry for my bad english
PS I'm working with LibreOffice 5.2
Sorry, the column after the 2nd select is "id_order"

Comment: Without seeing your table structure or at least the query response it's impossible to figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `order by` and `limit`:

```
SELECT "id_ordine", SUM( "quantity" * "price" ) "Total spending" 
FROM "t_orders", "t_products" 
WHERE "t_orders"."id_products" = "t_products"."id_products" 
GROUP BY "id_order"
ORDER BY "Total Spending" DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Your query would not work in most databases, because `id_order` is not aggregated and not in a `GROUP BY`.  MySQL accepts the syntax but just gives an order from an indeterminate row that is being processed.

Comment: I started studying mysql just 4 days ago, i don't know how it works yet, but I think that i'll use your answer because it's easier and more beautiful. Thank you, bro.
PS Could you explain me with simple words why my query wouldn't work in most databases? PS the column after the 2nd select was "id_order", my fault

Comment: @Robz . . . Your query will not work because `MAX()` turns the query into an aggregation query.  `id_ordine` is not aggregated and not an aggregation key.

Answer (score 0):

That's true cause your inline view (OR) subquery result doesn't include the column named `id_order`. Include that column in your subquery before you can fetch the same.

```
SELECT MAX( "Total spending" ), id_order 
FROM (
  SELECT "id_ordine", 
  SUM( "quantity" * "price" ) "Total spending",
  id_order                                     //Add this column
  FROM "t_orders", "t_products" 
  WHERE "t_orders"."id_products" = "t_products"."id_products" 
  GROUP BY "id_order"
)
```

Comment: Sorry, the column after the 2nd select is "id_order"